# jQuery .height() not working with box-sizing: border-border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav bar that I have positioned 'fixed' at the top of my page. The problem that I have is that I want to displace the entire page down by the (dynamic) size of my nav depending on the size of the screen used. Basically, I want to move the whole page down the height of this nav. To do this, I'm going to be using a padding to the nav that will affect it's height. I am using a box-sizing:border-box attribute on this nav but whenever I try and load the page, it doesn't account for the extra height added with the padding when I use jQuery's .height() function.

The div with the 'displacement' class does not have anything to it except a 100% width initially.  This is the ugly result along with all of the current code

http://jsbin.com/qomepe/2

Can anyone tell me why this is happening or if I've overlooked something?

Comment: This makes no sense.  if you are trying to do anything according to a screen width use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: try using: var height = $('header').outerHeight();

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything with the width. I'm trying to apply a height to this ".displacement" div using the same height of the 'fixed' nav bar.

Comment: Matthew, that worked perfectly! I had no idea this existed. I guess I was looking in the wrong place(css rather than jquery docs). Thank you

Comment: No problem, it looks good :) it just looks at the paddings, borders and margins for a more accurate size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using .outerHeight() to get the height of the navbar.

From jQuery API docs:

"The top and bottom padding and border are always included in the .outerHeight() calculation; if the includeMargin argument is set to true, the margin (top and bottom) is also included."

http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

Answer (score 1):

```
var height = $('header').outerHeight();

$('.displacement').css('height',height);
```

Try something like this

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see previous answer, it's the same